# Why is it called WEP?

Tags: wifi, terminology, wep

The WEP standard is called "wired equivalent privacy"?

Why does it include "wired"? Does have it have to do with ethernet codes or something else?

Comment: Perhaps because they were hoping to achieve Privacy Equivalent to that normally provided by Wired networks, even after moving to a broadcast/wireless medium?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English, not about security.

Answer (score 4):

> Wired Equivalent Privacy (WEP) is a security protocol that is designed to provide a wireless local area network (WLAN) with a level of security and privacy comparable to what is usually expected of a wired LAN.

[Source](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Wired-Equivalent-Privacy)

So as the name states, it's an equivalent of the wired network (LAN). It is supposed to provide the same level of security and privacy, but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: Privacy and Security means e.g. physical access restriction and the common used encryption standards like des/rsa etc or something else ? Thanks

Comment: On a wired network it is usually assumed (sometimes correctly, sometimes incorrectly) that it is difficult for an external attacker to get physical access to the network whereas a wireless network can be easilly sniffed. So to achive an equivilent level of privacy/security to an unencrypted wired network a wireless network needs to be encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

The security protocol is called Wired Equivalent Privacy (WEP) because it was initially designed to provide a wireless LAN with a level of security and privacy equivalent of a wired LAN.

However since it's inception it has not completely held up to the name which has resulted in WEP2, WEP+, WPA, WPA2, and other alternatives to be developed through it's lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

A very small amount of research is required to answer this.

It's Wired-Equivalent - a protocol designed to match the privacy of being on a wired network, whilst being wireless.